# Correct JDBC Connection URL for a PostgreSQL DB in a Docker Container

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, gitpod

I am using **Gitpod** cloud IDE which uses **Docker images** to provide a nice **linux environment** with **VSCode IDE**.

https://gitpod.io

It is possible to use a **Docker file** in Gitpod to install additional software in the environment. So by following Gitpod docs I installed **PostgreSQL**.

https://medium.com/gitpod/bring-your-own-docker-image-to-gitpod-52db1aa861de

I can now connect to the PostgreSQL with this command. **Note that I had to provide the sockets folder to get this working**.

`psql -h ~/pg/sockets postgres`

I have a **spring boot application** which should connect to the **PostgreSQL DB**. The connection URL is taken from an Environment variable.

`export JDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://gitpod@127.0.0.1/postgres`

And this is what I have in my **properties file**.

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.maxActive=10
spring.datasource.maxIdle=5
spring.datasource.minIdle=2
spring.datasource.initialSize=5
spring.datasource.removeAbandoned=true
```

this is what I get when I run **\du** on **psql** to list the users.

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 gitpod    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

The Gitpod user logged in to this linux environment is named **gitpod**. ( I do not know the password )

When I run the command **netstat -plunt | grep postgres** I get the following output

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      955/postgres
```

But when I run my App it throws the following exception

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: gitpod@127.0.0.1
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:75) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
```

I think it should be a problem with the Connection URL. Can someone please explain me how to get this working ?

Really appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't put the user in the URL, put it in the `spring.datasource.username` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working in gitpod with the help of the gitpod community.

Used the prebuilt postgres docker image by gitpod team as discribed in this doc to install postgreSQL.
https://www.gitpod.io/blog/gitpodify/#postgresql

And I changed the URL to the following

`export JDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?user=gitpod`